# Interactive simulation with OPCUA in OMpython

Tags: python, modelica, opc-ua, openmodelica

I trying run openmodelica test model with opc-ua interface in python.
Test model:

```
model test1

  input Real x1(start = 0);
  input Real x2(start = 0);
  input Real x3(start = 0);

  output Real y1;
  output Real y2;
  output Real y3;
equation

  der(y1) = x1;
  der(y2) = x2;
  der(y3) = x3;

initial equation

  y1 = 0;
  y2 = 1;
  y3 = 2;

end test1;
```

Scrip for model run (executing in terminal1):

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()


cmds = ['cd()',
        'cd("../")',
        'loadModel(Modelica)',
        'loadFile("package.mo")',
        'simulate(tests.test1, stopTime=1000.0, simflags="-embeddedServer=opc-ua -embeddedServerPort=4841");getErrorString()']

for cmd in cmds:
  answer = omc.sendExpression(cmd)
  print("\n{}:\n{}".format(cmd, answer))
```

Script (test1_opcua.py) for connect to model (executing in terminal2):

```
from opcua import Client

model = Client ("opc.tcp://localhost:4841")
model.connect()
modelObject = model.get_objects_node()
modelID = modelObject.get_children()

for id, i in enumerate(modelID):
    if id==0:
        print('{}) {} -'.format(id, i.get_browse_name()))
    else:
        print('{}) {} - {}'.format(id, i.get_browse_name(), i.get_value()))

print(modelID[12].get_user_access_level())
modelID[12].set_writable()
modelID[2].set_value(True)
```

In termina2 I have:

```
Requested secure channel timeout to be 3600000ms, got 600000ms instead
0) QualifiedName(0:Server) -
1) QualifiedName(1:OpenModelica.step) - False
2) QualifiedName(1:OpenModelica.run) - False
3) QualifiedName(1:OpenModelica.realTimeScalingFactor) - 0.0
4) QualifiedName(1:OpenModelica.enableStopTime) - True
5) QualifiedName(1:time) - 0.0
6) QualifiedName(1:y1) - 0.0
7) QualifiedName(1:y2) - 1.0
8) QualifiedName(1:y3) - 2.0
9) QualifiedName(1:der(y1)) - 0.0
10) QualifiedName(1:der(y2)) - 0.0
11) QualifiedName(1:der(y3)) - 0.0
12) QualifiedName(1:x1) - 0.0
13) QualifiedName(1:x2) - 0.0
14) QualifiedName(1:x3) - 0.0
```

But after command `modelID[2].set_value(True)` (I trying to start test model) in termina1 I have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fmutest1_opcua.py", line 12, in <module>
    answer = omc.sendExpression(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/OMPython/__init__.py", line 628, in sendExpression
    answer = OMTypedParser.parseString(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/OMPython/OMTypedParser.py", line 120, in parseString
    return omcGrammar.parseString(string)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3814, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text, found '"'  (at char 15774), (line:150, col:1)
```

How I can correctly build interactive model with OMpython and opcua?
I runing all the scripts in docker container. Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian

EXPOSE 4841
EXPOSE 4842

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install gnupg2 -y
RUN apt-get install lsb-release -y
RUN for deb in deb deb-src; do echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt `lsb_release -cs` stable"; done | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
RUN wget -q http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/openmodelica.asc -O- | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3 -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install openmodelica -y
RUN pip3 install https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMPython/archive/master.zip
RUN pip3 install matplotlib
RUN pip3 install opcua

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" artyom
RUN su artyom
USER artyom
ENV USER artyom

WORKDIR /TPPSim02/python

CMD [ "python3", "./test1_opcua.py"]
```

Comment: Seems the OMPython parser has issues parsing the result of the simulate command because of the opcua additional flags and additional output. I would suggest doing buildModel(tests.test1, stopTime=1000.0) and then run the executable from python directly using the extra simulation flags.

Comment: Thanks, if I run the model from terminal `./tests.test1 -embeddedServer=opc-ua -embeddedServerPort=4841 -rt=1` it works correctly.

Comment: I am guessing something in the simulation output is not escaped properly so OMC outputs bad data according to OMPython.